# How to conditionally assign colors to a stacked bar plot?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have the following dataframe:

```
      key1 key2 key3 ...
time
Jan   0.5  0.4  0.2  ...
Feb   0.3  0.4  0.4  ...
Mar   0.2  0.4  0.1  ...
Apr   0.5  0.3  0.8  ...
...   ...  ...  ...
```

I created a bar chart plot as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ax = df10.plot(kind='bar', figsize=(15, 10), fontsize=12, stacked='true')
plt.show()
```

This gives me a stacked bar chart with many bars and many colors, which does not provide a good overview at first glance.
I thus want to highlight only those bars that make an impact (>0.5) and hide the unimportant ones (by coloring them grey).

The goal is therefore some conditional coloring: bars, whose values are below 0.5 should be colored in grey, the rest should receive predefined colors.

I tried so many ways and cant find a solution that works. I am pretty new to python/matplotlib.
Can anyone help me please? Thank you very much in advance, any help is highly appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

You could loop through all the patches of the ax, check whether they are a `Rectangle` and change the color depending on some condition.

Apart from changing the color, other options are changing the hatching style (`rect.set_hatch('x')`) or the transparency (`rect.set_alpha(0.4)`).

Here is some example code:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Rectangle

df10 = pd.DataFrame({f'key{i}': np.random.randint(2, 9, 12) * 0.1 for i in range(1, 7)},
                    index=['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'])

ax = df10.plot(kind='bar', figsize=(15, 10), fontsize=12, stacked=True, rot=0, color=plt.cm.Dark2.colors)

for rect in ax.get_children():
    if type(rect) == Rectangle:
        if rect.get_height() < 0.5:
            rect.set_facecolor('lavender')
ax.tick_params(axis='x', length=0) # optionally remove the tick marks on the x-axis
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Comment: Does this answer your question?